# Is it possible to upload a .ggb file?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, images

Some questions require diagrams to explain and we have an option to include image in the forms png, jpg etc.

But I am drawing the diagrams using geogebra. In geogebra, we have an option called "slider" which explains our need geometrically. Is it possible to upload a .ggb file?

Comment: I am not sure about ([meta-tag:images]) tag, but it is closest I can think of among the tags we have. Feel free to retag the question, if you find better tags or if you don't think this tag is suitable here.

Comment: [Geogebra applets in posts?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12696/geogebra-applets-in-posts)

Comment: It seems that some people [use geogebratube](https://www.google.com/search?q=geogebratube+site:math.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 6):

No. It is not.

You can export it to a png/jpeg/gif (if you need it animated) and upload it, though.